# Async test does go trough all functions

Tags: angular, unit-testing, typescript, karma-jasmine, testbed

When i try to run a test in karma jasmine it should go trough 2 services. 
However it does all the way to the last function but it does not come back with its return values.
Does anyone has a idea how it does not return something?

**My beforeEach**

```
 function checklistDbFactory(): PouchDB {
    // ... is just for sharing
    let db = new PouchDB("...");
    PouchDB.plugin(PouchFind);
    return db;
  }


  beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        {provide: CHECKLIST_DB, useFactory: checklistDbFactory, deps: []},
        DatabaseService,
        IndexService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }
      ]
    });
    backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

    service = TestBed.get(IndexService);
  }));
```

**My test itself**

```
it('function should return expectd json', async(() => {
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(<ResponseOptions>{
        body: JSON.stringify(expectJson)
      }));
    }); 
    console.log("getting into main thread");
    // ... is just for sharing
    service.filldatabase(inputJson, "...").then((data) => {
      console.log('getting into filldatabase');
      console.log(data);
    });
  }));
```

**filldatabase function**

```
filldatabase(jsonfile, key) {
    console.log('Getting into filldatabase of 1service');
      return this.databaseService.fillPouch(JSON.parse(jsonfile['_body']), key).then( (data) => {
        console.log(data);
        console.log("Getting into then of fillPouch in 1st service");
        return true;
      }).catch( () => {
        console.log("getting into catch of fillpouch in 1service");
        return false;
      });
  }
```

**fillPouch function**

```
fillPouch(json, key) {
    json._id = key;
    let push = this.db.put(
      json
    );
    console.log("push");
    console.log(push);

    return push;
  }
```

**Output of the test on IntlliJ**

```
'getting into main thread'
'Getting into filldatabase of 1service'
'push'
ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: []}
```

**Output of tests on cmd**

```
    ✔ Service should be created
LOG: 'getting into main thread'

LOG: 'getting into main thread'
LOG: 'getting into main thread'
LOG: 'getting into main thread'
LOG: 'Getting into filldatabase of 1service'
LOG: 'Getting into filldatabase of 1service'
LOG: 'Getting into filldatabase of 1service'
LOG: 'Getting into filldatabase of 1service'
LOG: 'push'
LOG: 'push'
LOG: 'push'
LOG: 'push'
LOG: ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: []}
LOG: ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: []}
LOG: ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: []}
LOG: ZoneAwarePromise{__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: []}
.    ✔ function should return expectd json
// again file is just for sharing
31 10 2017 13:04:07.375:WARN [web-server]: 404: /assets/XML/<file>.json
LOG: 'Calling getJsonFromFile'

LOG: 'Calling getJsonFromFile'
LOG: 'Calling getJsonFromFile'
LOG: 'Calling getJsonFromFile'
```

Here is something weird as well. The `Calling getJsonFromFile`. is inside my app.component.ts. But i do not call this anywhere.

**The function inside where the log is in is**

```
getData() {
    this.databaseService.valueExist('checklistindex').then((data) => {
      if(!data) {
        console.log("Calling getJsonFromFile");
        this.indexService.getJsonfromFile().subscribe((data) => {

          console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
          this.indexService.filldatabase(data,'checklistindex' );
        })
      }
    })
  }
```

as you can see i do get all the way inside my fillPouch. However it does not return push. or anything what so ever along the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by mocking my dataservice the right way.

**databaseServiceMock**

```
import {DatabaseService} from "../../../../services/databaseService/databaseService";

export class DatabaseServiceMock extends DatabaseService {
  constructor() {
    super(null);
  }

  fillPouch(json, key) {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }

  valueExist(key) {
    return Promise.resolve(true);
  }

  getIndexVersion(key) {
    return Promise.resolve("TRIAL VERSION v2");
  }

  }
```

By mocking the databaseService i had to make some adjustments inside my `TestBed` as well.

**My beforeEach now**

```
beforeEach(async(() => {

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpModule],
      providers: [
        {provide:DatabaseService, useClass: DatabaseServiceMock},
        IndexService,
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backend, options) => new Http(backend, options),
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        }
      ]
    });
    backend = TestBed.get(MockBackend);

    service = TestBed.get(IndexService);
  }));
```

And my test looks like

```
it('function should return expectd json', async(() => {
    service.filldatabase(inputJson, "testpouch").then((data) => {
      expect(data).toBeTruthy();
    })
  }));
```

The issue of this question lies within `this.db.put(json)` cause of i did not mock my databaseService decent it did not go further here. i changed the fillPouch a bit to to make it easier to test.

**my fillPouch**

```
fillPouch(json, key) {
json._id = key;
return this.db.put(json).then(() => {
  return Promise.resolve(true);
}).catch((error) => {
  return Promise.reject(false);
});
```

}

This is all done with PouchDB

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine has support for async tests, you need to accept an additional argument for it:

```
it('function should return expectd json', async((done) => { // <-- add this parameter
    backend.connections.subscribe(connection => {
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(<ResponseOptions>{
        body: JSON.stringify(expectJson)
      }));
    }); 
    console.log("getting into main thread");
    // ... is just for sharing
    service.filldatabase(inputJson, "...").then((data) => {
      console.log('getting into filldatabase');
      console.log(data);
      done(); // <-- tell Jasmine you're finished
    });
  }));
```

The `done` function that is passed in gives you five seconds before you time out (By default), you can change this with `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL = 10000;` if you really need to - although five seconds is quite a long time already.

You can use the `done` pattern for `beforeEach`, `it`, and `afterEach`.

Comment: i already tried that that does not work. However i added some things to my question which may be useful